# how to "hide keyboard on touch up inside" when using invisible button that covers entire scrollview - can I have both?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uiscrollview, keyboard-events

If the invisible button covers the whole screen then it gets all the touches and I can't scroll.  If I delete the button then scrolling works like a champ.

How do I construct the layers so that I can have both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use notifications. Register for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. Then when the keyboard is coming up, add your button to the view hierarchy. Similarly, remove the button from the view hierarchy as the keyboard is on its way out.

Register for these notifications in `-viewDidLoad` and be sure to remove yourself as an observer in `-viewDidUnload`;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {

        [self.view insertSubview:self.keyboardDismissalButton atIndex:0];

    }];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {

        [self.keyboardDismissalButton removeFromSuperview];

    }];
}
```

Comment: One point of "noob confusion" on my end...  When you refer to "self.keyboardDismissalButton", that is not a system name, right?  How would I name my button in order to reference it in this manner?  Via and IBAction?

Comment: This sample assumes that your view controller would have a property called keyboardDismissalButton that would be either connected to a button in IB or created in code.

In your header:
`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *keyboardDismissalButton;`

And then synthesize it in the implementation:
`@synthesize keyboardDismissalButton;`

Then make the connection in Interface Builder.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your help.  I have the UIButton 'plugged' into IB, a property, and synthesized - and all looks good there.  I am getting a compile error on your block of code and have not seen this before.  Do you know what is wrong?   https://skitch.com/aibkwik/r1fib/vcaddcourse.m-gradetrack

Comment: Update:  I worked out the syntax error by adding usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification), where only the "^" existed before...  Now I get a clean compile but it still is not working...  Here are some screen shots.  Any ideas?   https://skitch.com/aibkwik/r188f/vcaddcourse.xib   and   https://skitch.com/aibkwik/r188m/vcaddcourse.m-gradetrack

Comment: I think I'm going to re-post as a new question - this has progressed now to a point where a new question could be better phrased.  Thanks for your help on this, getting me to this point.

Comment: No you're absolutely right, my code is wrong. That block does take a notification as an argument. You won't need it to achieve what you're attempting, but it does need to be declared. I've updated my code in case anyone else comes across this.

Comment: Dude, you rock.  Thanks for all your help - my form works great now.  Will upvote your response and check it off.  Take care.